# A way to show all my branches on github

Tags: github

I always have to go to a specific repository, click the switch branch button, type my branch name and finally arrive at what I want. Is there a way to submit advanced search terms into the search bar and return only my branches (the ones that I contributed to?)

Comment: Follow the feature request here: https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Feature-Request-Show-all-branches-across-all-repos/m-p/28418#M8005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to do this. While this is not definitive, my initial search of the help on github suggests that it's not currently possible. Based on this link: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/

```
Only the default branch is considered. In most cases, this will be the master branch.
```

Also, there's nothing about branches on the advanced search page, sad to say: https://help.github.com/articles/advanced-search/

Comment: man, that's too bad. I did a few searches myself, but I figured it was because I was bad, not that there was no solution. :(

Comment: Since at least 2016, there has been a way to do this, as given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51321004/323177

Answer (score 8):

have you tried to use

```
github.com/yourrepository/branches/yours
```

It works in my projects but I do not know if somebody have done that

Comment: This only works for "yourrepository". OP is asking for a way to see branches across *all* projects

Comment: a repository can have lots of branches, at the question this was not specified to be for different repos but branches

Comment: OK. I guess I misunderstood what "all my branches on github" means. I assumed that meant all branches on all repos on github.

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to point out that there is a graphical way to accomplish what is answered  [already here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51321004/1437269).

From https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-branches-in-your-repository/ :

> 1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
> 2. Above the list of files, click  NUMBER branches.
> 3. Use the navigation at the top of the page to view specific lists of branches:
>
>    - Your branches: In repositories that you have push access to, the **Yours** view shows all branches that you’ve pushed to, with the most recent branches first.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the `branches`. Then click on `yours` tab.

[image: Click on branchees]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**If your working in a organization's repository**

```
github.com/organization/yourrepository/branches/yours
```

else follow **@vmrvictor** answer

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this requirement myself. For the PowerShell savvy who want to see **all** their branches (not just those on a single repo) - here's the query I wrote to achieve this (outputs a formatted list of `RepoName` and `BranchName`):

```
# Your GitHub organisation/owner
$OrgName = "<Your organisation here>";

# Your GitHub PAT token
$PATToken = "<Your PAT token here>";

# Number of pages of repos you have
$NumberOfPages = 10;

1..$NumberOfPages | %{ 
  curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $PATToken" https://api.github.com/orgs/$OrgName/repos?page=$_ | ConvertFrom-Json 
} | %{ 
  $Name = $_.name; curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $PATToken" https://api.github.com/repos/$OrgName/$Name/branches | ConvertFrom-Json | %{ 
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 
      RepoName = $Name; 
      BranchName = $_.name 
    }
  }
}
```

n.b. GitHub paginates the response from the first API call, hence the input range with a higher limit of `$NumberOfPages`. It seemingly doesn't matter if this value exceeds the *actual* number of pages of repos you have, although it will make the query run for longer so worth trying to find out how many repos you are expecting in total!